Wifi's connected, no internet access in Ubuntu Budgie 22.04LTS
so i use a macbook(2007) and i've installed the ubuntu budgie 22.04LTS. i can connect to the wifi using ethernet and it works fine but it doesnt do so wirelessly. please help. my machine uses "broadcom" wireless card.
ps: i've tried many distros (linux mint, zorin os, raspberry pi, etc) on the same machine, but all of them showcased the same error. i'd be grateful if someone can explain why this keeps happening.
thanks & appreciation,

i get this error: Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontendWaiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 2843 (unattended-upgr) when i try to install the firmware for the driver
